# Google Drive SDK: Modify application-owned file as user

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have a Google App Engine application that:

1. Authenticates a user and authorizes the [drive.file scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes);
2. Creates and stores a file on behalf of a user via an application-owned ['regular'](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts#use_regular_google_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts) Google account;
3. Shares that file with the user (grants write access).

However, when a user attempts to update one of these files via an authorized Drive service created by the app, the [following exception](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#403_the_authenticated_user_has_not_granted_the_app_appid_access_to_the_file_fileid) is raised:

`403: The authenticated user has not granted the app {appId} access to
the file {fileId}`.

What am I missing? Given that the file was both initially created by and is still owned by the application, why is it necessary for the user to specifically grant the application access to the file?

My goal is for users to modify files (to which they have write access, that are stored in/owned by an application-owned account) *as themselves* in order to maintain appropriate 'last modifying user' attribution.

Is there anything I can do to work around this, other than (a) authorizing the 'drive' scope, (b) using the Google Picker or Drive UI to 'explicitly' open files with my app (does this imply the file must live in the user's Drive account?), or (c) having my application-owned account perform all file update operations?

Answer (score 2):

File scope authorization is currently done as a user-app pair.  Each user must individually authorize the app to access to the file.

Given that, I think you've identified the possible solutions. For b, the file doesn't need to be owned by the user, they just need access to it.  Having shared it with them should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I guess my understanding is incomplete. Haven't users already given the app permission to access these files by authorizing the drive.file scope?  Given the paradigm I described above, does this mean I must use the Picker UI for file management?  If this is the case, is there any way to use the Picker to directly create new files or delete existing files?

Comment: Each user must individually authorize the app to view each file as the user.  A different user authorizing the app does nothing for the current user.  Files created by the app can always be accessed by the app with the same user.